# Wrong math? Look like node Transform strange work

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, mathematics

I am having the following problem. I need to create two identical circles with a given number of edges. Then rotate one of them relative to the other along the Z axis to the desired angle. The angle is equal to half the division of the circle by the number of edges. For example, I need to make a circle of 7 edges. The second circle is also made of 7 edges and is rotated by 360/(7*2). That is, each point of the second circle is located on q by the middle of the edge of the first circle. This must be done with nodes in order to be able to change the size and number of edges. Below is my example and it doesn't work as it should. The math counts correctly, but the rotation is not at the desired angle. What am I doing wrong?[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe the translation of 2.6mm?

Comment: No. Translation is right. Second circle must be above the first and must be rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transfer your own values to a socket that accepts angles/rotations, then these must always be defined in radians instead of degrees.

The socket *Rotation* therefore does not require $\frac{360}{7}$ but $\frac{2\pi}{7}$

[image]

Comment: I suspected about radians, but the labels in the cells spoke about degrees and this deceived me. Thank you!

Comment: @ZzigzzZzigzz You're welcome!